# mysql.connector не работают запросы SELECT

Tags: python, mysqlconnector

делаю запрос в базу данных а ничего и не происходит даже выводил сам запрос 0 ответа от бд, хотя бд подключается всё правильно.

```
def get_info(username):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `discord_accounts` WHERE `UserName` = %s", (username, )).fetchone()

def get_items(username):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `discord_inventory` WHERE `UserName` = %s", (username, )).fetchone()

data = get_info(username)
print(data)
inv = get_items(username)
print(inv)
```

И ничего не происходит...

Comment: А почему должно что-то происходить? Результат вызова `fetchone()` вы нигде не используете и просто выбрасываете в никуда, а функции всегда возвращают `None`

Comment: `UserName = %s"` - username - скорее всего, строка, а значит оформлять запрос нужно, как для строки (`'`): `UserName = '%s'"`

Comment: @Frehzy не нужно, mysql-клиент сам автоматически подставит нужные кавычки

Comment: @andreymal и как я должен сделать правильно?

Comment: @EOS ну, вернуть что-нибудь из функции через `return` например?

Comment: @andreymal делал и тоже ничего не происходило.

Comment: @EOS если не происходит прям совсем-совсем ничего — вы уверены, что показанный вами код вообще запускается?

Comment: @andreymal да функция работает, я перед запрос дебажил и выводило сообщение, но запрос не работает.

Comment: Даже если сделать вот так ```return print(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `discord_accounts` WHERE `UserName` = %s", (username, )))``` ничего тоже не происходит

Comment: @EOS на самом деле внутри ваших функций происходит ошибка AttributeError, но если у вас ничего не происходит — значит вы где-то перехватили и подавили ошибку. Исправьте свой код так, чтобы он не подавлял ошибки, а выводил их куда-нибудь

Comment: Сделал try except и всё ошибки начали появляться)